# PHP Charset UTF8mb4 ,special characters are not saved into phpmyadmin when copied

Tags: php, mysqli, character-encoding, utf8mb4

I'm having a weird problem ,not sure what the title should be and I searched before posting this ,the collation of my database is set to `utf8mb4_general_ci`
and so is the column, 
yet when I type into the text field of that column the php code saves it just fine,how ever when this special text is copied from somewhere the column stays empty !
     I already have this set in my code

```
 $this->connection = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
 $this->connection->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following function before inserting it into database ,in which input_data is the data which you want to store in database . And the problem is database dont allow special character , and mostly these character are use for SQL injection , so  this function do the cleaning stuff by escaping ,so the data is safe to save.

```
$mysqli->real_escape_string($input_data);
```

follow this link for documentation 
[mysqli::real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: I have this class 
    `class MySQL {
    public $connection;
    public function __construct($autoConnect = false) {
        if ($autoConnect === true) {
            $this->connect();} }
    public function connect() {
        $this->connection = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
$this->connection->set_charset('utf8mb4');
         exit(); }} `
**now this is how I call it ,I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here** 
       `$mysql = new MySQL(true);
        $description = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysql, $description);`

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli(true);

Comment: let me know if still problem exist @user1702856

Comment: the same issue  still exists ,nothing is saved in database

Comment: I have this class